# Predict vector of random variables from historical data?

Tags: time-series, random-variable, joint-distribution, multivariate-distribution

There's historical prices for `gold`, `sp500`, `silver`, `iron`.

Historical data is a series of vectors, a **vector of prices for every day**.

```
1970-01-01  1970-01-02  ...  2010-01-01
gold-1      gold-2           gold-n
sp500-1     sp500-2          sp500-n
silver-1    silver-2         silver-n
iron-1      iron-2           iron-n
```

How to generate (predict) one thousand possible realisations of that vector for the next month?

I intentionally treat **daily prices atomic, as a vector** and not as separate streams of individual random variables.

We should take into account that **correlations are not constant in time**, for example some products (almost all commodities and stocks) will suddenly fall down all at the same time in crisis, with correlation ~1.

We assume that individual prices of `gold`, `sp500` etc. have **Pareto Distribution** with $\alpha \sim 2$.

Comment: Have you looked into any modelling techniques from quantitative finance?

Comment: @DemetriPananos I checked Modern Portfolio Theory but discarded it as it's limited with market risk only and not designed for modelling systematic risks. Also it's Gaussian and here's distribution is different. I also checked Monte Carlo - but it would require to know joint probabilities, and as I mentioned I would like to avoid dealing with it explicitly, they are not stationary and there's probably not enough data to calculate full Joint Probability Distribution properly.